# Error in (function( classes,fdef, mtable)

Tags: r

I'm trying to set a crs and evaluate min and max for a dataset, but I keep getting an error. My hunch is that something went wrong when I was setting the DSM_HARV, because although it ran without error, it's not functioning properly when I try to use it by name in code.

Here is the error message I'm receiving:

> ```
> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>   unable to find an inherited method for function ‘setMinMax’ for signature ‘"character"’
> ```

Here is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

raster("HARV_dsmCrop.tif")

DSM_HARV <- "HARV_dsmCrop.tif"

DSM_HARV <- setMinMax(DSM_HARV)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For code debugging please always ask with reproducible data per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirement. If there's no error on reproducible data then focus on the difference between your data and the example data to find the problem.

Comment: @Hack-R ... go ahead and point OP to your canonical question: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451).

Comment: @Parfait Will do

Answer (score 0):

The error message is relatively clear:

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘setMinMax’ for signature ‘"character"’

You are trying to use the `setMinMax` function on a character (string) value. That makes no sense. The word "HARV_dsmCrop.tif" has no min and max numerical values.

You could do

```
library(raster)
DSM_HARV <- raster("HARV_dsmCrop.tif")
DSM_HARV
DSM_HARV <- setMinMax(DSM_HARV) 
DSM_HARV
```

But it might not be necessary to use setMinMax as these values may be known already from the tif file.